# What is the best way to manage add-on products in Magento?

Tags: magento

I have an Magento-based ecommerce store and I want to have product add-ons (e.g. chocolates) that customers can add to their orders.

- Add-on products should not be visible in the regular catalog.
- My products either will have add-on products or not (i.e. I'm not doing different combinations of add-ons for different customers)
- If I add a new add-on product, it should show on every product that has add-ons enabled

What is the best way in Magento to create add-on products? Are there any modules that will work well for this.

Comment: I think you need to give some more examples or description.  Describe how these add-on products are different to cross-sell or up-sell.  How would they be presented to customers?

Comment: The issue with magento cross-sell is that each product has a unique up-sell product, which is hard to manage. In my store all products have the same three cross-sell products.  Are there any modules that allow you to manage add-ons/cross-sells easily for all products like this?

Comment: @william tell: I see that you have accepted an answer. The downside with that approach is that your add-on products will remain in the cart when the main product is removed. Ideally, I would think the addon products cannot be purchased by themselves. I'm thinking about writing an extension because I need to do something similar. Have you found a existing solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some solutions I can think of:

**I**

- Create all your add-on products as normal products.
- For each product that has add-on, add the add-on products to cross-sell or related-products of the product.
- Set the visibility attribute on 'Catalogus' and don't add them to any categories.

**II**

- (Create all your add-on products as normal products.)
- Make grouped products of your product and any add-ons you want to add.
- Set the add-on products on 'Don't visible individually' and probably the original products also.
- Add the grouped products to the category structure.